# nasm: Is "global _start:" allowed?

Tags: assembly, nasm

My code looks like this:

```
section .text

global _start:

_start:

...
```

If I compile it with:

> nasm -f elf test.asm

I get no errors and after linking the program is working for me.

The problem now is that my tutor couldn't compile my program and had to remove the ":" in the line `global _start:` to make it work.

1. How can it be that I get no error and can compile?
2. Is the ":" allowed/legal and the program should work?

Comment: `nasm -felf64`: no error 2.11.06.  `yasm -felf64`: `nasm-syntax.asm:1: error: invalid arguments to [global]` with v1.3.0.  It looks like the parse happens to accept it, but you shouldn't count on it.  Other than maybe saving a keystroke in copy/paste, it has no advantages, and is non-standard, so don't do it.  Terminology: "doesn't assemble" or "can assemble".  You don't compile asm source.

Comment: The name of the label is `_start`, not `_start:`. Would you use colons when referring to the label otherwise, e.g. `jmp _start:` ?

Comment: @PeterCordes It was one of my first assembly programs and I really don't remember why I put a ":" there :( I won't do it anymore. Does this mean it assembles for you without problems and runs? Or just assembles without problems?

Comment: @Michael In this programm I never referred/jumped to _start. But when I jumped I did not use colons, just "jmp loop".

Comment: @Crypto: It assembles, but there are no instructions in the copy/paste.  `...` isn't a valid x86 instruction.  So I didn't bother linking / running it, because it would just SIGILL right away.  Because I didn't bother putting any instruction in.  I checked, and `nm nasm-syntax.o` says it has the symbol `_start` like it's supposed to.  So yeah, it looks like it would actually work with this version of nasm, but not yasm.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay thank you very much. I would accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find out why NASM might not reject that:

> GLOBAL, like EXTERN, allows object formats to define private
> extensions by means of a colon. The elf object format, for example,
> lets you specify whether global data items are functions or data:
>
> `global  hashlookup:function, hashtable:data`
>
> Like EXTERN, the primitive
> form of GLOBAL differs from the user-level form only in that it can
> take only one argument at a time.

-- http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html

So it's just a quirk of the parser.  It assembles, but I didn't check what it assembled to.

Do Not Do This.  It's obviously wrong, and you shouldn't expect it to work.  It only happens to work by luck.  As always in these cases, stick to the normal syntax when there's nothing to be gained from doing otherwise.  Even if you don't confuse the compiler/assembler, you will confuse other human readers.